# Get a JSON item that is inside a JSON item Java

Tags: java, json

So I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
    "accessToken" : "<dont need this>",
    "clientToken" : "<nor this>",
    "selectedProfile" : {
        "id" : "<nope>",
        "name" : "<I need this>",
        "legacy" : true
    },
    "availableProfiles" :
    [
        {
            "id" : "<not this>",
            "name" : "<not this>",
            "legacy" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

So what I need is `selectedProfile` > `name`. I am able to extract `selected profiles`, would I just repeat the process on that? What should I do to retrieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Your question is very strange. You claim you are able to access key which doesn't exist in your JSON (unless by `selected profiles` you mean `availableProfiles`) but you can't access key which exist.. Can we see your code at least? Also what library are you using?

Comment: yes, show your existing code

Answer (score 3):

Using [javax.json](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html)

```
 JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(yourString);
 JsonObject base = reader.readObject();
 JsonObject profile = base.getJsonObject("selectedProfile");
 String name = profile.getJsonString("name");
```

and then name should be the object you want.

Comment: In theory he could also have gone for making similarly looking Java classes, and then parsing his Json via Gson. But I approve of this solution.

Comment: @MrKickkiller thank you. Your approval means a lot to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String name = yourJSON.getJSONObject("selectedProfile").getString("name").toString();
```